# What is the correct way to implement a 'useless loss' with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model that has two outputs:

- `output` is the true output of the network on which the loss is going to be computed
- `additional` is used to make an external task during inference (no loss should be computed with this output)

When I build the model, I write something like that:

```
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[output, additional])
```

Since my `Model` has two outputs, I need to provide two losses when compiling the model so I created a useless loss like this:

```
class NoopLoss(object):

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
        return self.compute_loss(y_true, y_pred)

    def compute_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.math.square(0.0)
```

Which I integrate in the compile step like this:

```
loss = UsefulLoss()  # the real loss I'm using
noop_loss = NoopLoss()

model.compile(loss=[loss, noop_loss], optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

It works, but I feel it is a bit hackish, is there a correct way to implement this behavior? I didn't find any official useless loss in the Keras documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Keras was not thought to consider things like this.
I often use these hacks myself too.

But, not sure it's a better solution, actually it might not be, you can create a training model and an inference model, both sharing the trainable part:

```
inputs = Input(...)
trainable_out = SomeLayer(...)(inputs)
....
trainable_out = ....

extra_output = SomeLayer(...)(something)    

training_model = Model(inputs, trainable_out)
inference_model = Model(inputs, [trainable_out, extra_output])
```

You can train `training_model` and automatically the other model will be trained as well.